# Set date to min and max in android before api 11

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker

I am not able to set date picket dialog to min and max dates.
User is able to scroll infinitely upward and backward to select any year or date. but i want to use a restricted datepicker dialog.
Can any one hep me out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried and tested !

**DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.java**

```
public class DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange extends DatePickerDialog {

static int maxYear = 2005;
static int maxMonth = 11;
static int maxDay = 31;

int minYear = 1955;
int minMonth = 0;
int minDay = 1;

public DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange(Context context,
        OnDateSetListener callBack, int minYear, int minMonth, int minDay,
        int maxYear, int maxMonth, int maxDay) {
    super(context, callBack, maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
    this.minDay = minDay;
    this.minMonth = minMonth;
    this.minYear = minYear;
    DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxDay = maxDay;
    DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxMonth = maxMonth;
    DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange.maxYear = maxYear;
}

@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    super.onDateChanged(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

    if (year > maxYear || monthOfYear > maxMonth && year == maxYear
            || dayOfMonth > maxDay && year == maxYear
            && monthOfYear == maxMonth) {
        view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
    } else if (year < minYear || monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear
            || dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear
            && monthOfYear == minMonth) {
        view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);
    }
}
}
```

**MyAndroidAppActivity.java**

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {


DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange datePickerDialog= null;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerOnDateSetListener;
Calendar myCalendar;

private TextView tvDisplayDate;
private Button btnChangeDate;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblDate);
    setDate();
    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

    btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            datePickerDialog.show();

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // set date picker as current date

        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerOnDateSetListener, intCurrentYear, intCurrentMonth,intCurrentDay);
    }
    return null;
}

private int intCurrentYear;
private int intCurrentMonth;
private int intCurrentDay;
private int intMaxYear;
private int intMaxMonth;
private int intMaxDay;
private int intMinYear;
private int intMinMonth;
private int intMinDay;


public void setDate() {
    /*
     * Initialise Listener for date set
     */

    datePickerOnDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year)
                    .append("-").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-")
                    .append(dayOfMonth));
        }
    };

    // initialise DatePicker 

    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    intCurrentYear = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    intCurrentMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    intCurrentDay = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    intMaxYear =  intCurrentYear;
    intMaxMonth = intCurrentMonth;
    intMaxDay =  intCurrentDay;

    intMinYear =   2011;
    intMinMonth = intCurrentMonth;
    intMinDay =  intCurrentDay; 

    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialogWithMaxMinRange(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, datePickerOnDateSetListener,intMinYear,intMinMonth,intMinDay,intMaxYear,intMaxMonth,intMaxDay);
}
```

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current Date (M-D-YYYY): "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code for custom Date Picker Dialog with restricted to particular limit.

**DatePickerRestriction.java:-**

```
package com.anil.android;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatePickerRestriction extends Activity {

 private TextView tvDisplayDate;
 private DatePicker dpResult;    

 private int mYear;
 private int mMonth;
 private int mDay;
 static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;

 //these variables are used to set max years need to set on Date Picker dialog...
 int minYear1 = 2000; 
 int minMonth1 = 0;//0-january , 1-february , 2-march..
 int minDay1 =1;

 int minYear = minYear1;
 int minMonth = minMonth1;
 int minDay = minDay1;

 //these are the minimum dates to set Datepicker..
 private int year;
 private int month;
 private int day;    

 public String dateOutput=null;


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 

        setCurrentDateOnView();

    Button pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);
    pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
    });

 }

 // display current date
 public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

    System.out.println("----------setCurrentDateOnView()-----------");

    tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, just add 1
            .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
            .append(year).append(" "));

    // set current date into datepicker
    dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
 }


 //this was the main part in program to Restrict the DatePicker Dialog  to only its current date.
 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    System.out.println("----------onCreateDialog()-----------");
    DatePickerDialog _date = null;

    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            _date =  new DatePickerDialog(this,  datePickerListener,
                    year, mMonth, mDay){
       @Override
       public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
       {   
           System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"+mYear+"--"+year);
           System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"+mMonth+"--"+monthOfYear);
           System.out.println("----------onDateChanged()-----------"+mDay+"--"+dayOfMonth);


          /* These lines of commented code used for only setting the maximum date on Date Picker.. 
           * 
           * if (year > mYear && year)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

               if (monthOfYear > mMonth && year == mYear )
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

               if (dayOfMonth > mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);*/


           //these below lines of code used for setting the maximum as well as minimum dates on Date Picker Dialog..
           if (year < minYear)
               view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);

               if (monthOfYear < minMonth && year == minYear  )
               view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay );



               if (dayOfMonth < minDay && year == minYear && monthOfYear == minMonth)
               view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);


               if (year > mYear)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

               if (monthOfYear > mMonth && year == mYear)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

               if (dayOfMonth > mDay && year == mYear && monthOfYear == mMonth)
               view.updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

              dateOutput = String.format("Date Selected: %02d/%02d/%04d", 
                                          dayOfMonth, monthOfYear+1, year);
              // Log.d("Debug", dateOutput);

              Toast.makeText(DatePickerRestriction.this,dateOutput,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   };      
    }
     return _date;
  }


 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {            

        System.out.println("----------onDateSet()-----------");                                

        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year).append(" "));

        // set selected date into datepicker also
        dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);
    }
 };

}
```

**main.xml:-**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Current Date (M-D-YYYY): "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with DatePicker but The documentation doesn't show any methods which can restrict the maximum date the Picker displays, still you can always check for the date it returns and can notify the user about validation criterion.